# How to convert custom dataset json file to yolov8 text file format in python

Tags: data-conversion, yolo, custom-data-attribute, file-format

I pulled the class names and x,y points I needed from the json file and created a csv file. This csv file contains rows for multiple regions for each image. For example, while there are 5 regions for 1.png in the dataset, there are 8 regions for 2.png, so there are non-fixed region numbers and values are given in each row. The number of x,y points in each region is equal. Based on the example, I want to export the lines containing the 5 region values found for 1.png into a single txt file and obtain the 1.png.txt format. The CSV file contains all the image names, regions and x,y points together. How can I perform this operation?

I tried to take the image names into a list and compare them with the image column of the csv, and if the names are equal, I tried to open a txt file and print it, but I could not succeed.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this situation:

```py
with open("data.csv", "r") as input_file:
  reader= csv.reader(input_file)
  for row in reader:   
    with open(str(row[5])+'.txt',"a") as output_file:
      output_file.write("".join(row[1])+" "+"".join(row[2])+" 
        "+"".join(row[3])+" "+"".join(row[4])+
        "\n"
      )
```

In my csv file row[5] represents the csv row containing the image names, which should be the name of the text files.

In the `output_file.write()` function, the row numbers of the features I want to get from the csv are given.

You should use 'a' when opening `output_file()` for printing. If you use 'w', the text file will be opened and reprinted, deleting its contents each loop.